# For each value in a series, return value from another pandas series, if the values of series1 are a substring in series2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the example bellow, I am trying to make a new column `df1['new']`. What I want is to look up the values of `df1['city']`, and see if they are a substring of any of the rows in `df2['des']`. If they are, I want `df1['new']` to have the values of `df2['des']:` (in this example, a description of the city).

`df1['city']`:

```
    city
0   New York
1   Amsterdam
2   London
3   Karachi
```

`df2['des']`:

```
    des
0   London is the capital and ...
1   Amsterdam and New York are two...
2   Karachi is the capital of...
```

This is what I want

```
        city                                  new
0   New York    Amsterdam and New York are two...
1  Amsterdam    Amsterdam and New York are two...
2     London        London is the capital and ...
3    Karachi         Karachi is the capital of...
```

At the moment, the closest I have gotten to solve it is this:

```
df['new'] = df.loc[df.des.str.contains("London"), 'des']
```

Which outputs:

```
    city            new
0   New York        NaN
1  Amsterdam        NaN
2     London        London is the capital and ...
3    Karachi        NaN
```

What I want is to, instead of just passing in `"London"` in the conditional, pass in the entire series `df1['city']`. If I do that though, i get this error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Well... the df2['des'] has no duplicates or? First match?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you just want **one** match, in the case where there are duplicate matches. Otherwise, any solution will be more complex.

With these problems, instead of iterating rows, it's often better to iterate your cities and use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). For example, you can create a dictionary:

```
d = {city: df2.loc[df2['des'].str.contains(city, regex=False), 'des'].iat[0] \
     for city in df1['city']}
```

Then map to `df1` via [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['des'] = df1['city'].map(d).fillna('No match found!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using list comprehension:

```
df1['new'] = [next((i for i in df2['des'] if x in i), 'Not found!') for x in df1['city']]
```

And another using regex and str.extractall:

```
matches = df2['des'].str.extractall('({})'.format('|'.join(df1['city']))).reset_index(0)
m = matches.set_index(0)['level_0'].map(df2['des'])
df1['new'] = df1['city'].map(m).fillna('No match!')
```